# Gem 2.3.1 and Ruby 2.3.3 versions don't match?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I am following the tutorial on deploying a Rails application on to Heroku, I am trying to install the dependencies, when I type in the command, `jruby -S bundle install --binstubs`

I get the following

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1
```

I've looked through different forums as they where a few people discussing but have tried and have come to no conclusion, specially for Windows as I only have access to that temporarily this week.

Information on the system: 
Windows 10

```
ruby -v    ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]
rails -v   Rails 5.1.4
gem -v     2.7.1
```

Do I have to downgrade my Ruby version, or install a concurrent older version? I don't see a 2.3.1 on the Ruby website? Should I use a package manager on Windows(If this is the answer looks like I will be spending a lot longer learning about this), would that solve the problem?

Comment: Open your gemfile.lock file and verify the Ruby version mentionned. Is it version 2.3.3 ? Also do you have mentioned a Ruby version in your Gemfile ?

Comment: On my Gemfile, I have the RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.1p0 (jruby 9.1.8.0)                                                                         While on my gemfile.lock I don't see any Ruby version. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The guide you are following is for JRuby, but it does not look like you are running JRuby on your machine (you are running a different type of Ruby). Make sure you [install and are using JRuby per the instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-jruby#introduction)

Comment: I have JRuby(jruby 9.1.8.0) installed, on my computer.

Comment: Maybe, but another ruby is taking precedence